# How to exclude this type of uids from data and extract only the users who have not logged in since one year

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

```
 def handle(self, **options):
        last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
        clients = Client.objects.filter(lastConnection__gte=last_month).values_list('uid','lastConnection')
        #print list(clients)
        last_year = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 365)
        uid_list = Client.objects.filter()
        last_year_clients = Client.objects.filter(lastConnection__gte=last_year,uid__starstwith="%0000000000000000000000000009897").values_list('uid','lastConnection')
        print list(last_year_clients)
```

This is the handler and the module is as follows:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    img = models.TextField()
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastConnection = models.DateTimeField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=128,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s"%self.uid
```

I want to extract the users who have no logged in since one year and the ids starts with "u'%000000000000000000000000000'"
Basically i want to exclude this type of ids and list the users who have not logged in since one year.

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_year = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 365)
        uid_list = Client.objects.filter()
        last_year_clients = Client.objects.filter(lastConnection__lte=last_year).exclude(uid__startswith="%00000").values_list('uid','lastConnection')
        with open("last_year.txt","wb") as fp:
                for s in last_year_clients:
                        fp.write(str(s)+"\n")
```